# Signaling to users of component that binding a property is not safe

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I found the following QML component [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-state.html):

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: myRect
    width: 100; height: 100
    color: "black"

    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: myRect.state == 'clicked' ? myRect.state = "" : myRect.state = 'clicked';
    }

    states: [
        State {
            name: "clicked"
            PropertyChanges { target: myRect; color: "red" }
        }
    ]
}
```

Let's call it "MyRect.qml". Since MyRect overrides the `state` property, binding it to a property won't work:

```
Item {
    id: root

    MyRect {
        id: inner

        state: root.state // not safe
    }
}
```

Assigning it will however work:

```
Item {
    id: root

    onStateChanged: inner.state = root.state // safe

    MyRect {
        id: inner
    }
}
```

On the other hand both binding and assigning would be safe for the property `width` of `MyRect.qml`.

How can a user of `MyRect.qml` know which properties are safe to bind and which are not without having to examine the source code?

Comment: What do you expect? The binding is only unidirectional, so when you assign a new value to `state` then you have two rivaling assignments: The outer object tells it to be `""` and the inner tells it to be `"clicked"`. It can't be both, so qml needs to make a decision and takes the last one.

Comment: The problem is that the user of component doesn't know this as the source code of the component is not known. Preferably QML should be extended with functionality for component creators to signal this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.
For `States` specifically, it is a bad idea to use the root-nodes states for internal states. You should either use the states of a hidden (internal) object, or you can directly resort to the [`StateMachine`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-statemachine-statemachine.html)  or to [`StateGroup`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-stategroup.html)s

Other than that you will need to resort to `Binding`-objects. Those can't be overriden. So if you take your example:

```
Item {
    id: root

    Binding {
        target: inner
        property: 'state'
        value: root.state
    }

    MyRect {
        id: inner
    }
}
```

The internal value should be overwritten everytime there is a state change to the root state.

Generally it is more important to make sure, internal bindings are not overridden, so you should use `Binding`-objects when creating reusable components whenever you want to bind one of the exposed properties to internal values.